# I am trying to generate release note using azure pipeline but facing issue on wiki page updater

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using wiki page updater task
I tried with AUTH token and use build machine credentials also

[this is exception which i get in release not generation pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCPon.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Build Agent Credentials. You need to make sure the build service account have the proper permission to contribute to the wiki repo.

Go the wiki security page shown as below:

[image]

Search for account `{ProjectName} build service ({OrganizationName})`, and make sure the Read/Contribute permission is set to allow.

[image]

If you were using PAT token. You need to make sure the PAT has the proper wiki Read/Write scope. See below:
[image]